# Regex to get content between single and double quotes php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have code like:

```
preg_match_all(UNKNOWN, "I need \"this\" and 'this'", $matches)
```

I need the REGEX that would have the `$matches` return just two entries of “this” without quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think following should work:

```
$str = 'I need "this" and \'this\'';
if (preg_match_all('~(["\'])([^"\']+)\1~', $str, $arr))
   print_r($arr[2]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] => this
)
```

Comment: It should be noted that this causes problems with things like `"don't"`, as the negated character class restricts both cases at the same time. That could be solved using an ungreedy `(.+?)`, an alternation with one alternative each for `'` and `"` or a negative lookahead `((?:(?!\1).)+)`. I guess the alternation would be the cleanest and most efficient of those possibilities.

Comment: @m.buettner: Thanks but I didn't see requirement of nested quotes in OP's requirements.

Comment: well, if you're going just by the requirements that are apparent from the OP's post, then Robert Podwika's and Alexey's patterns are the way to go ;).

Comment: @m.buettner: That is your opinion and I don't want to comment on that :) I don't want to unnecessarily complicate a solution if that is not a requirement. You can see some of very complex regex in my other answers only to cater those requirements.

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is wrong or necessarily incomplete. I just wanted to add the comment to make the OP aware of a possible limitation.

Comment: @m.buettner: I am in complete agreement with you here, I am ready to provide more complex regex as & when OP needs it.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/"(.*?)".*?\'(.*?)\'/', "I need \"this\" and 'this'", $matches);
```

But note that the order of quoted strings matter here, so this one will capture ONLY if both quoted strings (single and double) are there AND they are in this order (double - first, single - second).

In order to capture each of them individually, I'd launch preg_match twice with every type of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/(this).*?(this)/", "I need \"this\" and 'this'", $matches)
```

or if you want text between quotes

```
preg_match_all("/\"([^\"]*?)\".*?'([^']*?)'/", "I need \"this\" and 'this'", $matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
preg_match_all('/(["\'])([^"\']+)\1/', "I need "this" and 'this'", $matches)
```

It requires that the opening and closing quote be the same, and that there are no quotes in between.  The results you want will go into the second capture group.

To make the regex as reliable as possible, restrict what it matches as much as possible.  If the *this* portion of the regex can contain only letters, use something like `[a-z]+` (possibly with case insensitivity) instead.

Comment: I don't think that any regex flavour is supporting this. It would be sometimes nice if you think about a single character, like it is here the case, but what would happen if the backreference contains a longer word? That wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @stema, you are right.  It was a failure of my testing the regex (it successfully matched on the data with `\1`, but the character class wasn't actually *working*).  Thanks for catching the mistake.

Comment: @dan1111 you still need to escape the first `'` and the pattern has the same problem as the accepted answer (seeing it's the samepattern) in that it would not be able to match things like `"don't"`

Answer (score 0):

You can downvote this answer as much as you want, but in some case you can do:

```
$str = "I need \"this\" and 'this'";
$str = str_replace('\'','"',$str);
$arr = explode('"',$str);
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    if(!($key&1)) unset($arr[$key]);
print_R($arr);
```

So let it be in answers too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow optional text before, between and after the any amount of strings in quotes AND you you want the quotes to be in any order this will work:

```
preg_match("~^(?:[\s\S]*)?(?:(?:\"([\s\S]+)\")|(?:'([\s\S]+)'))(?:[\s\S]*)?(?:(?:\"([\s\S]+)\")|(?:'([\s\S]+)'))(?:[\s\S]+)?$~", "some \"text in double quotes\" and more 'text to grab' here", $matches);

$matches[1]; // "text in double quotes";
$matches[2]; // "text to grab"
```

This will match all of the following:

```
Some "text in double quote" and more in "double quotes" here.
"Double quoted text" and 'single quoted text'.
"Two" "Doubles"
'Two' 'singles'
```

You can see it in action here on Regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/XAsewv/2