# get content from string php regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the next string:

```
$string = '["["123456","NAME","1","INFORMATION","15/12/2015","","","0","OTHER ATTRIBUTE","",""]","["["123", "OTHER"]"';
```

I want to extract the alphanumeric information between double quotes, I tried with this answer

[Regex to get content between single and double quotes php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098223/regex-to-get-content-between-single-and-double-quotes-php)

but the output was this,

```
[0]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(3) ""["" [1]=> string(3) "","" [2]=> string(3) "","" [3]=> string(3) "","" [4]=> string(3) "","" [5]=> string(3) "","" [6]=> string(3) "","" [7]=> string(3) "","" [8]=> string(3) "","" [9]=> string(3) "","" [10]=> string(3) "","" [11]=> string(3) ""]"" } [1]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(1) """ [1]=> string(1) """ [2]=> string(1) """ [3]=> string(1) """ [4]=> string(1) """ [5]=> string(1) """ [6]=> string(1) """ [7]=> string(1) """ [8]=> string(1) """ [9]=> string(1) """ [10]=> string(1) """ [11]=> string(1) """ } [2]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(1) "[" [1]=> string(1) "," [2]=> string(1) "," [3]=> string(1) "," [4]=> string(1) "," [5]=> string(1) "," [6]=> string(1) "," [7]=> string(1) "," [8]=> string(1) "," [9]=> string(1) "," [10]=> string(1) "," [11]=> string(1) "]" }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input `"["123456"`... is different to the [link you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098223/regex-to-get-content-between-single-and-double-quotes-php). And no single quote here.

An idea would be to require a `\w` [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) in pattern for at least one `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

```
if(preg_match_all('/"([^"]*?\w[^"]*)"/', $string, $out) > 0)
  print_r($out[1]);
```

- `[^"]*` matches any amount of characters, that are [not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `"`. The `?` after `*` makes it [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).
- Find matches in `$1` what's captured by first [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (parenthesized group).

[See demo and more explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jB0cZ3/2) or [PHP demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/524955)

Comment: How Could I set a position in the array generated where there is only ""?, I mean there is no alphanumeric characters but must be a position there.

Comment: @JoseRojas Hi! You can make the group optional with `?` after it: [`"([^"]*?\w[^"]*)?"`](https://regex101.com/r/mZ5wF5/1) [see demo](https://eval.in/525478)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regey with preg_match_all :

```
\"[^\"\,\[\]]+\"
```

You can test it here : http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/eKH